# Cocoapods and Swift/iOS 8 Does Not Compile for Device

Tags: ios, swift, compilation, cocoapods, redefinition

I'm attempting to compile an application for an iPhone 6 with the following cocoapods frameworks:

AFNetworking
AlamoFire
Swifty
Pods

The application compiles and runs in the simulator no problem.  However, attempting to compile for a physical device (iPhone 6, iOS 8.4.1) generates 10+ "Redefinition of ..." errors on the iOS 8.4 socket.h header.

Redefinition erros are for 'linger', 'so_np_extensions', etc.

Maybe it's a small oversight but I've spent a little time on it already.

Thanks if you can help!